# How to access $scope object from multiple templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to login to an API with username and password and then get a token use it to get some resources, first is a post request and second is get request. both requests are made and I checked the scope object, I got both $scope.userInfo and $scope.projects. The problem is, after logging in, I am redirecting to home page which is a different template and trying to access $scope from there but, I get nothing

controller.js

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: './components/welcome.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  }).when('/home', {
    templateUrl: './components/home.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  }).otherwise({
    template: '404 Resource Not Found'
  });
});

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    var { username, password } = $scope;
    $http({
      url: 'url',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Client-Type': 'browser'
      },
      data: { username, password }
    }).then(function(response) {
      $scope.userInfo = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    }).then(function() {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url2',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Authtoken': $scope.userInfo.authtoken
        },
      }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.projects = response.data;
      }).then(function() {
        $location.path('/home');
      });
    });
  };
});
```

welcome.html

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Sign In</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" ng-model="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" ng-model="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn float-right login_btn" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
  <h1>Welcome username!</h1>
  <div class="user-details-container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 img">
        <img src="image-source"  alt="" class="img-rounded"> user avatar
        <img src={{user.avatar}} />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 details">
        <blockquote>
          <h5>User Template</h5>
          <h5>{{userInfo.user.name}} //</h5>
          <small><cite title="Source Title">Vancouver, BC Canada  <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></cite></small>
        </blockquote>
        <p>
          user details...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered success">
                <thead>
                    <tr class='text-primary'>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Project</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
                      <th>//{{project.number}}</th>
                      <th>//{{project.name}}</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <th>2</th>
                    <th>second project</th>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I am new to angularJS, thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is something unclear

Comment: Use an angular service to share data across various parts of the app. Although you are using same controller for both routes, each route initializes a different instance of the controller

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl using **service** fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to another place (home, ...) you will loss client side data. You should get the data from server again or don't redirect and only change the state (use single page features).
Also if you want to share data between controllers, you can use "factories" or "services".

Comment: OP ***is*** using single page features as shown in routing config. First part of this answer is way off track

Comment: Fine but that doesn't mean "client side data" is lost

Comment: You are rigth, I got it wrong with window.location @charlietfl . Still can use factory or service

Comment: Thanks for you help @Ramen, I just started using angular and not sure how to submit a form using services or factories, could you show me a way or some resources to start from in my case. Thanks

Comment: Yes I am aware of that and wrote about it in comment below the answer. It's the first part of your answer that is misleading

Comment: Services in angularjs are singleton, then if you inject a service in multiple controllers, all of them can have access to it. You start with angular tutorials like this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp @Hindreen